# Magento 2.1 - Creating a download link to files of a downloadable product

Tags: downloadable, magento-2.1.2, download-link

as the title suggests. I would like to create a download link to the uploaded file on a downloadable product.

I already have access to the downloadable product and call call the getLinkFile() that returns something like "a/b/file_name.pdf". However I am stuck on creating a link that will allow the customer to download the file.

All downloadables do not have price and customers do not need to purchase them. I am just looking at a way to provide these files (we are using downloadables due to another reason and require these links as a work around).

If you need anymore info I am happy to provide. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to work out what I needed to do and I thought I would share my result.

Within Magento_Downloadable I found that Link class passes the downloadable link information to the Download class by calling Downloads' _processDownload() method.

Link class:
{magento_directory}vendor/magento/module-downloadable/Controller/Download/Link.php

Download class:
{magento_directory}vendor/magento/module-downloadable/Controller/Download.php

Knowing this I just extended the Download class in my own module as a new Controller and created my own frontend route to it. All I need to do is pass to _processDownload the 2 parameters, link and link type and it works.