# Magento 2 linking to downloadable files

Tags: magento2

I would like to link to a PDF from a custom page but don't know where to put the pdf in the file structure and how to link to the PDF so that it can be downloaded?

Comment: This may help
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144129/magento-2-1-creating-a-download-link-to-files-of-a-downloadable-product